# What kind of product is $\prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, tensor-calculus

In the section 4.1 of [Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001106), Farhi et al proposes a quantum adiabatic algorithm to solve the $2$-SAT problem on a ring.

The adiabatic Hamiltonian is defined as 
$$
\tilde{H} (s) = (1-s) \sum^n_{j=1}(1-\sigma^{(j)}_x) + s \sum^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{2} (1-\sigma^{(j)}_z \sigma^{(j+1)}_z )
$$

To prove the correctness of the algorithm, the authors consider an operator which negates the value of the bits.
$$
G = \prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x
$$

**My question:**

What kind of product is $\Pi$? Is the elaboration of $\prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x$ , $\sigma^{(1)}_x \otimes \sigma^{(2)}_x \ldots \otimes \sigma^{(n)}_x$ or $\left(\left(\sigma_x \otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-1}\right)\cdot \left(\mathbb{I}\otimes \sigma_x\otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-2}\right) \cdot \left(\mathbb{I}_2\otimes \sigma_x\otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-3}\right)\cdot \ldots \cdot \left(\mathbb{I}_{n-1}\otimes \sigma_x\right)\right)$?

Comment: Both alternatives are the same if you identify $(A\otimes B)\cdot(C\otimes D) = (AC)\otimes (BD)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the forms you propose,
$$\sigma^{(1)}_x \otimes \sigma^{(2)}_x \ldots \otimes \sigma^{(n)}_x \tag1$$
and
$$\left(\sigma_x \otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-1}\right)\cdot \left(\mathbb{I}\otimes \sigma_x\otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-2}\right) \cdot \left(\mathbb{I}_2\otimes \sigma_x\otimes \mathbb{I}_{n-3}\right)\cdot \ldots \cdot \left(\mathbb{I}_{n-1}\otimes \sigma_x\right) \tag2$$
are actually equal. This is because the tensor products of matrices are (by definition!) associative in the precise sense that
$$(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=(AC)\otimes(BD).\tag3$$
Recursive application of $(3)$ to $(2)$ will reduce it to $(1)$. Hence both are valid implementations of the product $\prod^n_{j=1}\sigma^{(j)}_x$.

Answer (score 0):

It's both - those two "long form" expressions you wrote are equivalent.  Matrix multiplication distributes over tensor products, so when you multiply them together the $i$th factor in the tensor product just becomes $\sigma^{(i)}_x$ times a bunch of identity matrices.

Comment: Maybe "distributes over" is the wrong phrase to use, but you know what I mean - to multiply tensor products, you multiply each factor individually